# Using pcase to recursively parse nested lists

Tags: pcase

So I'm trying to process the following nested list...

```
(setq *test*
  '("mt" "trello"
    ("b" "board"
     ("l" org-trello-show-board-labels)
     ("d" org-trello-sync-buffer-down)
     ("u" org-trello-sync-buffer-up)
     ("s" "setup"
      ("c" org-trello-create-board-and-install-metadata)
      ("I" org-trello-install-board-metadata)
      ("u" org-trello-update-board-metadata)))
    ("c" "card"
     ("a" org-trello-assign-me)
     ("A" org-trello-unassign-me)
     ("x" org-trello-archive-card)
     ("X" org-trello-archive-cards)
     ("c" "comment"
      ("c" org-trello-add-card-comment)
      ("C" org-trello-delete-card-comment))
     ("k" "kill"
      ("c" org-trello-kill-cards)
      ("e" org-trello-kill-entity)))
    ("d" "from trello"
     ("b" org-trello-sync-buffer-down)
     ("c" org-trello-sync-card-down))
    ("g" org-trello-abort-sync)
    ("h" "help"
     ("k" org-trello-help-describing-bindings)
     ("v" org-trello-version))
    ("j" "jump"
     ("b" org-trello-jump-to-trello-board)
     ("c" org-trello-jump-to-trello-card))
    ("s" "setup"
     ("I" org-trello-install-key-and-token)
     ("c" org-trello-check-setup))
    ("u" "to trello"
     ("b" org-trello-sync-buffer-up)
     ("c" org-trello-sync-card-up))))
```

Using this recursive function:

```
(defun *test/pcase-test (prefix &rest tree)
  (pcase tree
    (`(,(and (pred consp) items))
     (pcase items
       (`(,(and (pred stringp) key)
          ,(and (pred stringp) label)
          .
          ,children)
        (push `(,*prefix-func 'org-mode ,(concat "m" prefix key) ,label) *result*)
        (apply #'*test/pcase-test (concat prefix key) children))
       (`(,(and (or (pred stringp) (pred symbolp)) key)
          ,(and (pred symbolp) fn))
        (push `(,*leader-key-func 'org-mode ,(concat prefix key) ',fn) *result*))))
    (_
     (error "Not a valid definition:\n%s" (pp-to-string tree)))))
```

NB: I usually begin this function by setting `*result*` as nil, and setting `*prefix-func` and `*leader-key-func` to specific function symbols. I plan to use `nreverse` to process it's final form.

The goal is to transform this nested list into a series of function calls, `*prefix-func` for nested lists beginning with two string items (while passing the subsequent items, i.e. `children`, into another recursive function call, and `*leader-key-func` for two-item lists consisting of a string (or a symbol) followed by a symbol (which could probably be `fboundp`, but I haven't decided on that yet).

What's mystifying me is that, when I [instrument](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Instrumenting.html#Instrumenting) this function and step through it, it run through the `(,(and (pred consp) items)` once, and then (since it runs the second nested `pcase`) it will match `(,(and (predp stringp) key)...`, pushing at least one item into `*result*`. But when I step through the second round of execution, despite the fact that when I type `e` and evaluate `(consp tree)` (which returns `t`), it doesn't match `(,(and (pred consp) items)` the second time.

I definitely don't understand what's happening, or even if I'm doing the right thing with `pcase` (I've gone through [this reference](http://newartisans.com/2016/01/pattern-matching-with-pcase/), [this EmacsWiki entry](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PatternMatching), and even [the original Emacs reference on pattern matching case](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Pattern-matching-case-statement.html), which I admit I don't fully grok. I *think* I'm doing the right thing, but there's a nuance here I'm not fully getting.

I note that if I replace the `(_...)` with the following code, it works, but I would like it if the function to throw an error if it comes up with a nested list it doesn't understand:

```
(items
  (dolist (item items)
    (apply #'*test/pcase-test prefix item))))
```

I know for a fact that the above code will break if `item` isn't a list, and I would rather that the function I'm using would just signal me early, rather than break further down the line. Plus, this feels like a cop-out, because then I'd just make a pattern-case that matches *anything* and hack a way out of my predicament, which *still* means I don't understand how `pcase` works.

What am I doing wrong? Anyone's insight on this would be *greatly* appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It might help if you pared down the example to just what's necessary to pose your question. IOW, isolate the specific problem more. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> (defun *test/pcase-test (prefix &rest tree)
>   (pcase tree
>     (`(,(and (pred consp) items))
> ```
>
> [...]
>   But when I step through the second round of execution, despite the fact that when I type `e` and evaluate `(consp tree)` (which returns `t`), it doesn't match `(,(and (pred consp) items)` the second time.

That pcase clause you cite is actually equivalent to `(and (= (length tree) 1) (consp (car tree)))`. To see this, simplify the pattern by ignoring the `pred`:

```
(pcase tree
  (`(,items))...)
```

The above checks that tree is a list of one element (and binds `items` to that element).  The `pred` that you added checks `items`, not `tree`.

---

> What am I doing wrong?

I'm guessing you make your initial call like this:

```
(let ((*result* nil))
  (*test/pcase-test "PREFIX" *test*)
  *result*)
```

In this case `tree` is a list containing single "definition" list, so the top-level call is okay.  Then for the recursive call, you passing a list of several "definition" lists:

```
(apply #'*test/pcase-test (concat prefix key) children)
```

In this case `tree` is a list which looks like `(("b" "board" ...) ("c" "card" ...) ("k" "kill" ...) ...)`.  You have nothing in your code to handle this multiple children case, so it doesn't work.